# Mixing Code-First gRPC with Contract-First gRPC

Tags: protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

Code-First = protobuf-net.Grpc.AspNetCore

Contract-First =  Grpc.AspNetCore

I followed the example projects and they communicate without error to their respective server client. However, if I mix and match (code-first to contract-first or vice versa) I get a method not implemented exception. The proto file matches the code first structure.

Is this a limitation of these approaches?

If so, how do we use Contract-First without writing mapper classes from existing entities to the ones defined in the protos file?

([Github solution of Greeter sample for both](https://github.com/MikeyGInTheMorning/MixNMatchGrpc))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining the Code-First service with the correct annotations works:

```
namespace CodeFirstLib
{
    [ProtoContract()]
    public partial class HelloRequest
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, Name = @"name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }

    [ProtoContract()]
    public partial class HelloReply
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, Name = @"message")]
        public string Message { get; set; } = "";

    }

    [ServiceContract(Name = @"greet.Greeter")]
    public partial interface IGreeter
    {
        ValueTask<HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(HelloRequest value, CallContext context = default);
    }
}
```

Comment: yup; that ^^^; or you could use `namespace greet`, but I think what you have is preferable